# Open Feature form in multi edit mode using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

Is there a way to use PyQGIS to open the Feature form in the multi-edit mode for the active layer selected features?

It's the "standalone" version of the one existing for the attribute table.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-multiple-fields

Or do I have to recreate the form like it's done in C++ in here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L9236